# Rock,Paper,Scissors round counter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a console version of rock paper scissors. The game is working for now but I can't run the for loop, what I want to do is at the end of each round, the console will say what round we are in and tell who won the current round. It will be the Best of 5 and the winner will be determined in round 5.

Since I'm a beginner I couldn't try too much. I know my code is not clean and complicated because I proceed by trying and I'm also new to Stackoverflow, if there is something missing in the topic, I apologize in advance for those.

```js
// PLAYER CODES
    let playerSelection = prompt('Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?')

        if (playerSelection === 'Rock' || playerSelection === 'Paper' || playerSelection === 'Scissors') {
            console.log("You chose " + `${playerSelection}`);
        } else {
            console.log('Error! Pick Rock, Paper or Scissors')
        }

    // COMPUTER CODES
    let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    function getComputerChoice() {
        let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
        let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        return random; 
     }

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
            return ('Draw')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Rock') && (computerSelection === 'Scissors')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Rock beats Scissors.')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Scissors') && (computerSelection === 'Paper')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Scissors beats Paper.')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Paper') && (computerSelection === 'Rock')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Paper beats Rock.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Scissors') && (playerSelection === 'Paper')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Scissors beats Paper.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Paper') && (playerSelection === 'Rock')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Paper beats Rock.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Rock') && (playerSelection === 'Scissors')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Rock beats Scissors.')
        }
    }

    function game() {
        for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
            playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
            if (i == 1)
            return ('Round 1') 
            else if (i == 2)
            return ('Round 2')
            else if (i == 3)
            return ('Round 3')
            else if (i == 4)
            return ('Round 4')
            else if (i == 5)
            return ('Round 5')
        }
    }

    console.log("Computer chose " + `${computerSelection}`);
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    console.log(game(playRound));
```

Comment: `game()` doesn't have any parameters. Why are you calling it with an argument `game(playRound)`?

Comment: you need to get a new player selection and computer choice inside the loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the sections to get the player and computer choices inside the loop. I fixed some other problems, too.

```js
    // PLAYER CODES
    function getPlayerChoice () {
      let playerSelection = prompt('Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?')
            if (playerSelection === 'Rock' || playerSelection === 'Paper' || playerSelection === 'Scissors') {
                console.log("You chose " + `${playerSelection}`);
                return playerSelection
            } else {
                console.log('Error! Pick Rock, Paper or Scissors')
                return getPlayerChoice()
            }
    }

    // COMPUTER CODES
    function getComputerChoice() {
        let choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
        let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        return random; 
     }

    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        if (playerSelection === computerSelection){
            return ('Draw')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Rock') && (computerSelection === 'Scissors')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Rock beats Scissors.')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Scissors') && (computerSelection === 'Paper')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Scissors beats Paper.')
        } else if ((playerSelection === 'Paper') && (computerSelection === 'Rock')) {
            return ('Player Wins! Paper beats Rock.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Scissors') && (playerSelection === 'Paper')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Scissors beats Paper.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Paper') && (playerSelection === 'Rock')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Paper beats Rock.')
        } else if ((computerSelection === 'Rock') && (playerSelection === 'Scissors')) {
            return ('Computer Wins! Rock beats Scissors.')
        }
    }

    function game() {
        for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
            console.log('Round ' + i)
            let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();
            let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
            console.log("Computer chose " + `${computerSelection}`);
            console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
        }
    }
game()
```